# Multiple database schema for different database in spring boot

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, schema, pcf

I have spring boot application that need to be deployed on PCF. I want to use H2 database for local testing but after deployed in PCF I will be using SQL server. I have a schema that need to be used for each database. So, I have two schema.sql file one for H2 and another for SQL server. How can I tell spring for local profile schema-H2.sql need to be used and for profile cloud schema-sqlserver.sql need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *spring.datasource.platform* to differentiate the schema and data sql file.
eg,

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
then the file name should be data-h2.sql and schema-h2.sql
```

Make sure you set *spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always*